# python/tkinter: is it possible to copy paste text AND tags?

Tags: python, tkinter

in my Text widget I have here and there many tags, taking care of the text appearance (bold, italic etc).

Tkinter takes care by default of cut/copy/paste in the text widget, but only of the text content, not of the associated tags. Do you know if it is possible to implement it?

I anticipate some problems if I would cut in the middle a region where e.g. bold text appears: I would have to leave behind a tag marker for 'bold begin' so that the remaining text is still bold...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to implement it. You can use the `dump` method of the text widget to get all the text and tags in a given range. To paste, you just have to use that information when inserting the text.

It gets somewhat complicated when you try to paste, say, italic text inside a range of already bolded text since you may have to retag the inserted text to have both bold and italic attributes. However, I know it can be done because I've done it with tcl/tk in the past.